# Flutter go_router, how to get the whole current stack of pages?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

Meaning if I go from a job screen to a client screen (the client the job was for), to another job screen (another job done for the client) etc, how can I display job > client > job?

And including parameters, so I could display Job 12 > SomeCompany > Job 17.

Sub routes aren't sufficient because the stack can repeat through multiple of the same pages infinitely.

Answer (score 8):

I have found one solution which relies on the internal API implementation.
This might break in the future so use it with care.

```dart
GoRouter.of(context).routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.matches
```

Returns [`List<RouteMatch>`](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/lib/src/matching.dart#L70)

> **ⓘ Tip for Beginners**
>
> Make sure you have configured the routes correctly in `GoRouter()`.
> Hope they are nested as the route goes down the navigation instead of being siblings to each other.
>
> Also, make sure that you give the whole URI location string to `GoRouter.of(context).go()` like `'/home/level-2/level-3'`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about checking the whole stack , but in case of anybody needed to check if there is a page on the stack , GoRouter has a canPop() method:

`` /// Returns `true` if there is more than 1 page on the stack. bool canPop() => GoRouter.of(this).canPop(); ``

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't possible with `go_router`.** `auto_route` has an API to check the stack, but `go_router` shows [no search results for `stack`](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/search.html?q=stack).

---

Instead of `GoRouter.of` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74098193/7365866), you could use the extension method `BuildContext#canPop`. For example, in my onboarding page, I have this logic to pop if I can, and if not possible (the first time someone launches the app), I replace the page.:

```
if (context.canPop()) {
  context.pop();
} else {
  context.replace(Routes.dashboard);
  // Or alternatively, allow the user to navigate back to onboarding with:
  //  context.push(Routes.dashboard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `GoRouter`, add a navigation observer `GoNavigationObserver` which extends the `NavigationObserver`.

override the `didPush` and `didPop` methods. And also have a class member as `List<String> backStack`. And you can always see the list of current Routes in the `backStack`.

```
class GoNavigationObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
    static List<String> backStack = [];
    
    @override
    void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
        backStack.add(route.settings.name ?? '');
    
        print(backStack.toString());
    }
    
    @override
    void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
        backStack.removeLast();
    
        print(backStack.toString());
    }
    
    @override
    String toString() {
        return backStack.toString();
    }
}
```